# Flutter: Call static code into pubspec.yaml for versioning dependencies

Tags: flutter

For example, I have a `dependecies_version.dart` file. And this is the code for that file.

```
class DependeciesVersion {
  static const http = "^3.2.1";
  static const bloc = "^6.0.5";
}
```

And on the `pubspec.yaml` file is like this.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: DependeciesVersion.http
  flutter_bloc: DependeciesVersion.bloc
```

It's possible?

Why I need this approach? Because I have each module with implemented same dependencies. So I just focus on `dependecies_version.dart` file for updating the version of dependencies instead of checking all `pubspec.yaml` file on each module.

> In Native we have `kotlin-dsl` for handle this if implementation `modular` concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for now not supported that way, but I fix it by creating a module/package only for handling dependencies.

[image]

So if your feature module needs those dependencies, just add it in `pubspec.yaml` in your feature modules.

```dart
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  dependencies:
    path: ../dependencies
```

Here is the example: https://github.com/rrifafauzikomara/NewsApp